# How to sync 2 or multiple node in ros2?

Tags: string, synchronization, ros, ros2

```
class Combine(Node):
    def _init_(self):
        super()._init_("combine")
        self.subs_hello_ = self.create_subscription(String, '/hello', self.callback_msg_hello)
        self.subs_world_ = self.create_subscription(String, '/world', self.callback_msg_world)
        self.received_hello_msg = None
        self.received_world_msg = None

    def callback_msg_hello(self, msg):
        self.received_hello_msg = msg
        self.combine_and_process_messages()

   # Callback for world topic


    def combine_and_process_messages(self):
        # Check if both messages have been received
        if self.received_hello_msg is not None and self.received_world_msg is not None:
            combined_message = f"Hello: {self.received_hello_msg.data}, World: {self.received_world_msg.data}"
            self.get_logger().info(f"Combined Message: {combined_message}")
```

I have subscriber node that subscribe two topics /hello and /world, and i want to combine the two into one and i want the node sync to publisher, but when i running it, the result is not sync and when i stop both or just once it still running with the last msg receive. so how can i sync msg ros2 just like this?

[ros2] hello1, world3

[ros2] hello2, world4

stoping just:

[ros2] hello3, None

stoping both:
.....................

Just waiting until both publish again

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [messagefilter](https://answers.ros.org/question/361637/using-c-message-filters-in-ros2/) for such problems